# How do I fetch data from 2 tables and display into 1 chartjs

Tags: php, html, mysql, charts, chart.js

I have two different tables.

Table 1: food (which have the food's name field)

Table2: food_details (which have the food's quantity field)

both are connected by food's 'id'.

I have created a chartjs chart to display the food's quantity chart-wise so right now the chart is connected to table 2 and is displaying my quantity with label of id. But my problem is, I want to display food's name as label with quantity but the field is in table 1 which I don't know how to fetch and display instead of food's id or even if it's possible.

Here is my code

Data:

```
<?php 

header('Content-Type: application/json');

define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_NAME', 'chartjs');

$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

if(!$mysqli){
    die("Connection failed: " . $mysqli->error);
}

$query = sprintf("SELECT id, available_quantity FROM food_details ORDER BY id");

$result = $mysqli->query($query);

$data = array();
foreach ($result as $row) {
    $data[] = $row;
}

$result->close();

$mysqli->close();

print json_encode($data);

 ?>
```

chart script

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost/chartjs/data.php",
        method: "GET",
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            var id = [];
            var available_quantity = [];

            for(var i in data) {
                id.push("id" + data[i].id);
                available_quantity.push(data[i].available_quantity);
            }

            var chartdata = {
                labels: id,
                datasets : [
                    {
                        label: 'Food Storage',
                        backgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75)',
                        borderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75)',
                        HoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
                        HoverBorderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
                        data: available_quantity
                    }
                ]
            };

            var ctx = $("#mycanvas");

            var barGraph = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'horizontalBar',
                data: chartdata
            });
        }, 
        error: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be looking for a `join`:

```
SELECT f.name, fd.available_quantity 
FROM food_details fd
INNER JOIN food f on f.id = fd.id
ORDER BY fd.id
```

This query retrieves the `name` of each `id` from the `food` table, and puts it in the first column instead of the `id`. Rows are still ordered by `id` - you can change that to `name` if that's what you want.